# how to encode R strings so that they are read into MySQL without encoding errors

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, rmysql

Consider this:

```
> scr<-paste("INSERT INTO ques2_log (freeze_time) value(",sQuote(now()),")")
```

`> scr`

```
#> "INSERT INTO ques2_log (freeze_time) value( ‘2017-06-13 23:46:16’ )"
```

If we feed this simple SQL script into a MySQL DB as follows:

```
dbExecute(db,scr1)
```

The MySQL DB throws the following error:`Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '��2017-06-13 23:44:13’ )' at line 1`

I have tested the SQL script by typing by hand and it works.

It is also clear that the single quote is the unexpected character.

I looked up some online articles on character encoding and tried
`enc2utf8(scr)` before feeding to the DB through RMySQL commands. No effect. Same error.

I also read [this](https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/issues/57#issuecomment-308064665) and ran

`ALTER DATABASE ques2_log CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

But the error remains.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `sQuote` rather than just plain old single `'`? Typically `sQuote` is used to format output to be displayed on screen, which isn't what you're doing here.

Comment: I am using sQuote to surround the output of the function **now()** by single quotes. It is difficult to surround the output of a function in single quotes otherwise, I guess.

Comment: Have you tried `paste0("'",date(),"'")`?

Comment: Yes! that worked. I never imagined that **sQuote()** and **'** would generate two different character codes for the same single output character! Please convert this as an answer @joran and I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Btw. `sQuote(date(), q = FALSE)` would also work but it isn't the best tool for the job. Also I would not recommend using `paste()` in this context. You are better off using `DBI::dbQuoteLiteral()` or [glue::glue_sql()](https://glue.tidyverse.org/reference/glue_sql.html) for e.g. correct `NA` handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use regular single quotes, as in:

```
paste0("'",date(),"'")
```

`sQuote` produces distinct left and right "smart" quotes, as documented in `?sQuote`:

> Single or double quote text by combining with appropriate single or
>   double left and right quotation marks.

...and additionally, the documentation makes clear that the intended purpose of this function is for formatting text for displaying user facing messages on screen:

> The purpose of the functions is to provide a simple means of markup
>   for quoting text to be used in the R output, e.g., in warnings or
>   error messages.

So it generally shouldn't be used for processing text to be used programmatically.